# OrientDB min() function not woking

Tags: orientdb

The problem statement is simple, I want to get the minimum price from PriceList.

class:PriceList - Properties:item (String), price (Double)

*select min(price) from PriceList* works but I want to achieve this using MATCH query

**Query :** MATCH {class: PriceList, as:C} RETURN min(C.price)

**Output** NullPointerException

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions are not supported in MATCH statement (as long as it doesn't support GROUP BY), the support will be extended in next version.

In the meantime, you can use a nested SELECT:

```
SELECT min(price) FROM (
  MATCH {class: PriceList, as:C} RETURN C.price as price
)
```

About the NullPointerException, it's definitely a bug, if you could report it on the official issue tracker https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues I'd take it a look